# Web Scraping in R using rvest and finding the html_note

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to find the current `html_note` to fetch the replies count for each post in this forum: https://d.cosx.org/. I used CSS selector and it said `.DiscussionListItem-count` but it seems not working.

My code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
COS_link <- read_html("https://d.cosx.org/")
COS_link %>% 
  # The relevant tag
  html_nodes(css = '.DiscussionListItem-count') %>%      
  html_text()
```

I would like to fetch the replies count, for example: 1k for 1st post and 30 for 2nd post. I am wondering if I miss something or anyone has a better idea?

Comment: I would look at the html code for the website.  I cannot read it, but sometimes there are items on the web page that are generated with javascript.  I think this is why your CSS selector is not working.

Comment: Thanks @BryanAdams. I guess so. I am trying to find any hacky way to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the API and parse the json response for the `title` and `participantCount` attributes

API endpoint returning that info is:

```
https://d.cosx.org/api
```

Substring the response to remove the trailing `0` and leading `ac76` then parse with a json library of choice.

---

Less optimal is to [regex](https://regex101.com/r/16vUhG/1/) out the json string from original url

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://d.cosx.org/"

r <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('body') %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      toString()

x <- str_match_all(r,'flarum\\.core\\.app\\.load\\((.*)\\);')  
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x[[1]][,2])
counts <- json$resources$attributes$participantCount
```

---

For those wishing to pair up the title with count and who don't have chinese settings a colleague helped me write the following:

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)
library(corpus)

url <- "https://d.cosx.org/"
r <- read_html(url) %>%
html_nodes('body') %>%
html_text() %>%
toString()

x <- str_match_all(r,'flarum\\.core\\.app\\.load\\((.*)\\);')
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(x[[1]][,2])
titles <- json$resources$attributes$title
counts <- json$resources$attributes$participantCount
cf <- corpus_frame(name = titles, text = counts)
names(cf) <- c("titles", "counts")

print(cf[which(!is.na(cf$counts)),], 100)
```